# Man page Solaris - Reformatting error

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I'm having problem with man page in Solaris.

```
bash-3.2# man tar  
Reformatting page.  Please Wait... done    
bash-3.2#
```

I tried googling around, I'm not sure anyone has encountered this kind of situation.

Comment: I would suspect a disk full situation.

Comment: I will try to free some space. Will update on the situation. Thanks

Comment: No improvement even after clearing some disk space. Maybe this has something to do with swap space because I keep getting swap space full, limit exceeded.

Comment: I have added extra 2.5GB swap space, everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man` needs free disk space in `/tmp` to complete reformatting the requested pages. If there is a disk full situation there, you get no output.

Comment: Edit /etc/vfstab so that

swap    -       /tmp    tmpfs   -       yes     -

Comment: Yes, or whatever action that free up space for `/tmp`.